# Reactive CSV selection then used in function as df

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and trying to combine a couple features and having some trouble.

I want for the user to be able to select a CSV and then be presented with a random instance (in this case tweet) from that table. The following code worked when "tweetData" was a statically loaded csv using read_csv.

```
## function to return random row number from data set
getTweet <- function(){
 tweetData[sample(nrow(tweetData), 1), ]
}

function(input, output, session) {
  ## set reactive values, get randomized tweet
  appVals <- reactiveValues(
    tweet = getTweet(),
    ratings = data.frame(tweet = character(), screen_name = character(), rating = character())
    )
```

I want to instead use a dynamically chosen csv for "tweetData", something like adding this??

```
csvName <- reactive(paste0('../folder_path/', input$file_name))
selectedData <- read.csv(csvName)
```

How can use reactively chosen csvs to fit into the structure of the first code chunk?

Comment: Do you want user to upload csv to the app? Check `?fileInput` https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/fileInput.html

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [`fileInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/fileInput.html) for giving user an option to upload a dataset.

This is a simple reproducible example -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(input$file1)
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```